# Instagram API - Get self media only

Tags: instagram

I'm trying to get only self media.

`/users/self/feed` --> this return user follow feeds

`/users/self/media/recent` --> return only recent post

I want to get all self media with this parameters, `count=10&max_id=?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this API with your `{user-id}`:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent/?client_id=YOUR-CLIENT_ID
```

this call will return max of 20 pics, then use the pagination.next_url in the API response to make the next API call to get the next 20 photos and so on...